# How to send custom command from client to server (LSP implementation)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

My implementation is based on 'vscode-languageserver' and I would like to know how to send custom requests to vscode server implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

server

```
const connection: LSP.IConnection = LSP.createConnection(LSP.ProposedFeatures.all);
connection.onNotification("handler/do", (handler)=>{});
```

client

```
let client:LanguageClient = <initialize>
client.sendNotification("handler/do");
```